# CSS 3 text shadow in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, web

I'm using CSS 3 text shadow to simulate bevel and emboss effect in my web app. The problem is IE 10 shows very bad looking shadow. I didn't checked it on IE 9 still now. But Can it be fixed?
This is the CSS I'm using ::

```
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #A4A4A4;
filter: dropshadow(color=#A4A4A4, offx=0, offy=-1);
```

Is there any javascript library to show text shadow in IE? or any other tricks that will help me? Or any extra CSS properties to add to solve this?

Comment: Have you read this **http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the other shadow filter.

```
.shadow {
    /* For IE 8+ */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
```

Or use a behaviour file that simulates CSS3:
http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

**Update**: Sorry, I misread, that shadow filter is for `box-shadow`, not `text-shadow`.
Internet Explorer does not suppurt `text-shadow`, but you can simulate this with a `drop-shadow` and a `glow` filter, see [this tutorial](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html).